# Fancybox closes on error

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox-2

I am using Fancybox to make a simple comment submission form; I'm very close, but when a field is left blank and an error message pops up, the box automatically closes.  Any ideas?

.js

```
$("#guest_submit").fancybox({
    'scrolling' : true,
    helpers : {
        title : null
    }
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#message_form").on("submit", function(){

        if ($("#guest_name").val().length < 1 || $("#guest_message").val().length < 1) {
            $("#guest_error").show();
            $.fancybox.resize();
            return false;
        }
        $.fancybox.showActivity();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            url: "/guestbook/",
            data: $(this).serializeArray(),
            success: function(data){
                $.fancybox(data);
            } 
        });
        return false;

    });
})
```

.html

```
 <div> 
        <form id='message_form' action="/guestbook/" method="post">
        <div id='guest_error'>
          <p class='error'>Make sure you fill out all fields!</p>
        </div>
          {% csrf_token %}
          <p>
            <label for="guest_name">Name: </label>
            <input type="text" id="guest_name" name="name"/>
          <p>
            <label for "guest_message">Message: </label>
            <input type="textarea" id="guest_message" name="message"/>
          </p>
          <input type="submit"/>
        </form>
      </div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Keep fancybox open on ajax error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19907238/keep-fancybox-open-on-ajax-error)

Comment: Well, that's embarrassing.  I duplicated my own question.