# Keep fancybox open on ajax error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fancybox

The way my code is structured, the fancybox closes automatically after briefly displaying the error message.  I'd like it to stay open so the user can fix his/her errors.  What am I doing wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#message_form").on("submit", function(){

        if ($("#guest_name").val().length < 1 || $("#guest_message").val().length < 1) {
            $("#guest_error").show();
            $.fancybox.resize();
            return false;
        }

        $.fancybox.showActivity();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            url: "/guestbook/",
            data: $(this).serializeArray(),
            success: function(data){
                $.fancybox(data);
            },


        });
        return false;

    });
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the `$.fancybox.resize();` line and it worked.  Yay.

Comment: If you are using fancybox 2, you should have used `$.fancybox.update();`

Answer (score 0):

You have an error callback for caching the ajax error.

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#message_form").on("submit", function(){

```
    if ($("#guest_name").val().length < 1 || $("#guest_message").val().length < 1) {
        $("#guest_error").show();
        $.fancybox.resize();
        return false;
    }

    $.fancybox.showActivity();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        url: "/guestbook/",
        data: $(this).serializeArray(),
        success: function(data){
            $.fancybox(data);
        },
        error: function(e){
            var error_data = e;
            $.fancybox(error_data);
        }


    });
    return false;

});
```

})

Comment: This gives me the same result--I briefly see the error message in the fancybox, then the box closes.  Also, I don't see much of a difference between the success and error functions here.